# Explanation about split in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have this task.

```
st = 'print only the words that sstart with an s in the sstatement'
```

and the solution would be

```
for word in st.split():
    if word[0] == 's':
        print word
```

why won't it work with

```
for word in st.split():
    if word[1] == 's':
        print word
```

I kind of understand what that zero stands for, but how can I print the words with the second letter being 's'.

Comment: Your question is to print words that start with s. But now you want to print words where the second letter starts with s?

Comment: Also, what you're doing can't work if `word` is only one character long.

Comment: It's working correctly, python is raising IndexError when the length of the `word` is only one.!

Comment: What about words that don't have a second letter (or even a first letter)? Also what exactly isn't working? Please provide a [mcve] including the expected output. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that **it is not guaranteed that the length of the string** is sufficient. For instance the empty string (`''`) or a string with one character (`'s'`) might end up in the word list as well.

A quick fix is to use a length check:

```
for word in st.split():
    if len(word) > 1 and word[1] == 's':
        print word
```

Or you can - like @idjaw says - use slicing, and then we will obtain an empty string if out of range:

```
for word in st.split():
    if word[1:2] == 's':
        print word
```

If you have a string, you can obtain a *substring* with `st[i:j]` with `st` the string, `i` the first index (inclusive) and `j` the last index (exclusive). If however the indices are out of range, that is not a problem: then you will obtain the empty string. So we simply construct a slice that starts at `1` and ends at `1` (both inclusive here). If no such indices exist, we obtain the empty string (and this is not equal to `'s'`), otherwise we obtain a string with exactly one character: the one at index 1.

In the case however you will check against more complicated patterns, you can use a ***regex***:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'\b\ws\w*\b')
rgx.findall('print only the words that sstart with an s in the sstatement')
```

Here we specified to match anything between word boundaries `\b` that is a sequence of `\w`s with the second character an `s`:

```
>>> rgx.findall('print only the words that sstart with an s in the sstatement')
['sstart', 'sstatement']
```

Comment: I was trying to be really anal and see if I can solve it using slicing and omit the length (just for fun), but that darn single character still requires the length check.

Comment: Thank you, regex is a bit complicated for now but i will surely note that down.

Comment: @idjaw You could use `word[1:2] == 's'`, that shouldn't require a length check :)

Comment: @MSeifert oh!!! gah! I was using `word[:2:2]`! Thanks :) Of course, now that I think about it, it is so obvious lol.....

Comment: thank's for the solution but coulld you explain how that works? word[1:2] == 's'  i really want to understand pythond and coding in general. quite new to this)

Comment: @Stelian [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1832539) answer explains slicing *perfectly*.